# How to sum up a total of two instances in a dice game, after rolling multiple times

Tags: c#

I have started a project, where it involves generating random numbers and reaching a certain total.

In this project, this is a dice game called "Twenty-One". It's where the user rolls a set of two dice multiple times, until it reaches a total of 21 (not in the number of rolls). During this time, when the user reaches a total of 15, only one die can be used to add up the remaining numbers. If the user reaches exactly 21, then a message will pop up saying he or she won; if it's over 21, then they lose. Here's an example:

```
2+5 = 7
1+3 = 4 (up to 11)
2+2 = 4 (up to 15)
3+3 = 6 (up to 21) "WINNER!!"
```

I've have a created a code for this problems, but it's a work in progress. I've also added to the code a series of if and else statements that will show the two dice. This is my code so far:

```
//"Roll The Dice" button click
private void btnRollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Generating random numbers
    Random random = new Random();

    int diceIntA = new int();
    int diceIntB = new int();
    int diaVal, dibVal, total;

    diceIntA = random.Next(1, 7);
    diceIntB = ranbom.Next(1, 7);
    diaVal = diceIntA + 1;
    dibVal = diceIntB + 1;
    total = diaVal + dibVal;

    lblTotal.Text(total.ToString());

    //Image of the first die
        if (diceIntA == 1)
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice1.Image;
        else if (diceIntA == 2)
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice2.Image;
        else if (diceIntA == 3)
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice3.Image;
        else if (diceIntA == 4)
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice4.Image;
        else if (diceIntA == 5)
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice5.Image;
        else
            pbdShow1.Image = pboxDice6.Image;

        //Image of the second die
        if (diceIntB == 1)
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice1.Image;
        else if (diceIntB == 2)
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice2.Image;
        else if (diceIntB == 3)
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice3.Image;
        else if (diceIntB == 4)
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice4.Image;
        else if (diceIntB == 5)
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice5.Image;
        else
            pbdShow2.Image = pboxDice6.Image;
}
```

After reviewing my code, I've thought up of so many ideas where I could add up the numbers of the two dice. An example of this is the following code:

```
int twentyOne = 21;
int oneDie = 15;

if (total = twentyOne) {
    MessageBox.Show("WINNER!");
}
else (total > twentyOne) {
    MessageBox.Show("You went over 21. You lose.");
}
```

If the latter code is not efficient, what other method should I use to make the dice total up to 21?

Comment: FYI ‘==‘ not ‘=‘. Oh...on my phone and hadn’t been able to scroll down in you’re top code. I see you are using it there.

Comment: This appears to be a code review...not seeing a problem statement.

Comment: @nkosi - it was possible that was causing the problem in the code.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question to leave only code that demonstrates whatever problem you have. Realistically there are not too many ways to express "add two numbers together" in C#...  but if you have particular concerns about `a+b` you should write them down in the post too.